# How to make entire GridView to ReadOnly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am able to make individual columns to be read only on Form load, but I want to set the complete grid view to be read only instead of setting each and every column to be read only. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you tagged it as WinForms I assume you are asking about `DataGridView`, it has property `ReadOnly`, set it to true.

Comment: Thanks. I can set it to Read only, but it looks like it is editable and the user will try to click on it. How can I grey it out ?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hi Kiriti, you can always comment out what make it worked for you, that will eventually help other users and community. :)